# Why am I asked for a password when NOPASSWD is set, but I can switch to root shell and run the same command without a password?

Tags: sudo

My current user is in `/etc/sudoers` as `currentuser ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

If I do `sudo -u postgres psql postgres` I am asked for a password, but if I do `sudo -s && sudo -u postgres psql postgres` I am not.

Why am I asked for a password the first time?

Comment: May be a line lower in the sudoers file that's matching -- without nopasswd

Comment: Can you confirm or deny other matching lines in the sudoers config? (Could be #include d from the main file)